# Self-signed ssl certificate doesn't work on mac OS Sierra

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, mac

I been trying all day long to get **https** work on my local website using self-signed ssl certificate.

I was following all the necessary instructions:

1. Generated .crt and .key files following the guide on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self
2. Configured nginx to use ssl

   ```
   listen 443;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
   ```
3. Added generated certificate into mac's keychain and checked it as 'Always trust'

But it didn't make https work and I keep getting Chrome's (or other browser's) "**Your connection is not private**"

mac OS Sierra 10.12.6, nginx installed via homebrew

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For CHROME 58 onwards, the self-signed certification has to be properly generated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42917227/3930651.

Comment: Chrome's Security tab helped me to find out the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I looked in Security tab in Chrome's dev tools and it turned out that Chrome requires subjectAlternativeName to match your domain name (not only Common name)

The following solution worked to me [Generating a self-signed cert with openssl that works in Chrome 58](https://serverfault.com/questions/845766/generating-a-self-signed-cert-with-openssl-that-works-in-chrome-58)