# Can not get rid of `net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error in chrome with self-signed certificates

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, http, openssl

There are numerous question on the web where people are having difficulty setting up self signed certificates for use on internal network.

Just to link a few:
[Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate/43666288#43666288)
[Chrome accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951939/chrome-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)
[Generating a self-signed cert with openssl that works in Chrome 58](https://serverfault.com/questions/845766/generating-a-self-signed-cert-with-openssl-that-works-in-chrome-58)
[StartCom certificate Error : ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/k5XA8tBfImk/4paszdmSDQAJ)

I have gone through each and every one of them but still can't get rid of the `(net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).` error.

Steps followed:

- key & certificate generation on server

  ```
  openssl req \          
  -newkey rsa:2048 \
  -x509 \
  -nodes \
  -keyout file.key \
  -new \
  -out file.crt \
  -subj /CN=Hostname \
  -reqexts SAN \
  -extensions SAN \
  -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
      <(printf '[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:192.168.0.1')) \
  -sha256 \
  -days 3650
  ```
- setting up server process (apache) to use the newly generated certificate and key file for secure connections
- exporting certificate file from the server on to the client by navigating to https://192.168.0.1:3122 through *Chrome Dev Tools* and using the *Export* option
- adding the CA to list of known Certificate Authorities (on Fedora 26) using

  - `certutil`
  - `sudo cp file.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors; sudo upate-ca-trust`
- restarting chrome

I have also tried various values for the `CN` field above like: `hostname`, `common.name.com`, `Common Name`, `192.168.0.1`

Even after all this the error persists when I navigate to https://192.168.0.1:3122 and I no longer know what I am doing.

The text representation looks similar to:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            9e:ae:33:24:3a:2d:2b:e2
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = Hostname
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 28 20:18:06 2017 GMT
            Not After : Oct 26 20:18:06 2027 GMT
        Subject: CN = Hostname
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:a4:80:6c:3a:1b:5e:c4:e6:f6:7d:a5:be:d6:cd:
                    d9:23:bd:1a:b1:e6:f1:e3:b0:76:47:37:a3:d8:b0:
                    60:44:23:c3:8a:58:1c:c3:0a:99:3d:42:32:ca:8b:
                    ec:31:9d:a8:df:6c:13:43:e6:78:12:b8:24:04:5a:
                    9f:6e:11:24:2a:56:e3:20:36:78:a4:cc:ed:45:7c:
                    a3:c1:36:7b:25:f6:6b:2d:01:59:02:74:8b:7a:13:
                    ec:83:63:90:2e:a0:a3:aa:23:de:ea:f0:8e:1f:99:
                    b9:50:b1:5f:64:e4:c9:91:c0:0c:56:15:3c:c0:ff:
                    0f:bf:e1:af:7a:bf:51:40:37:b0:34:20:95:a1:05:
                    14:k2:35:20:e8:98:48:65:ad:26:cc:de:a2:50:48:
                    77:8c:e2:7a:d5:bd:83:96:86:ef:20:79:2f:15:a3:
                    07:48:f4:1f:c7:9d:a1:4b:bd:ee:47:83:51:f3:09:
                    27:ed:b7:09:c8:56:40:0c:68:25:92:d8:62:dc:14:
                    6c:fa:f1:e3:93:1b:79:3c:58:9c:53:69:ff:6a:0f:
                    ee:4c:9f:8e:22:2d:62:6b:b3:ae:22:d6:e3:d0:bd:
                    06:43:a7:c3:e1:1e:23:07:61:b0:4e:64:14:92:0c:
                    5b:f1:a8:c5:29:67:64:7d:65:10:b9:60:41:b8:3b:
                    1y:1f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:192.168.0.1
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         11:65:6d:86:04:7f:5a:b0:ce:b2:6e:95:7e:03:8c:fe:a9:d0:
         81:2c:6f:50:63:2e:91:77:79:cd:27:32:b0:19:2b:ac:ea:c0:
         4b:f7:56:d9:be:34:54:f1:a6:1d:bc:d0:3b:bb:bf:90:0e:2d:
         1d:83:28:97:8e:f8:37:5d:3e:00:5a:cd:3d:36:5d:c4:5d:a8:
         7e:a4:59:f0:91:3d:af:3d:28:03:3e:78:3b:5b:0a:fb:24:34:
         02:a2:09:ec:d6:0c:58:63:ab:69:26:5e:fe:1d:1f:19:54:0f:
         68:4e:31:f9:de:1e:de:86:81:3f:b7:62:c5:67:02:05:a2:7a:
         03:f4:b5:3b:ba:c4:ba:26:8e:a2:ee:1c:ef:69:63:07:b0:97:
         fd:a8:42:e2:11:6d:de:b5:70:a5:4a:62:d2:62:d9:5b:17:f4:
         d5:cd:6f:71:75:dd:35:33:55:52:2e:30:29:f8:42:ec:b9:d3:
         82:85:a1:e7:f6:f5:90:dd:cb:07:15:a7:44:70:1c:93:e6:ec:
         03:3a:be:41:87:3c:f0:a4:88:a5:65:d9:29:2c:78:de:90:b8:
         6a:8b:99:6e:d0:e5:8c:08:a4:71:51:fd:1d:e1:8c:0c:17:d5:
         b0:31:fc:7f:99:23:dd:1a:c4:0b:45:17:68:88:67:c6:22:df:
         2b:ac:ea:c0
```

Please note that this is my 1st time setting up SSL/TLS certificates for such purposes. Please advice on how to get rid of the error.

Comment: Add a text representation of your certificate to your question. Use `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <filename>`.

Comment: I have added the text representation.

Comment: I think, Chrome expects IP address to be encoded as IP address in SAN extension, not a DNS name.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[Chrome 58+ no longer matches the Common Name (`CN`) in certs.](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/security-dev/IGT2fLJrAeo)

Now it uses Subject Alternative Names (`SAN`) instead.

`SAN` must contain proper `DNS` or `IP` entry.

- When DNS is used, it should be a resolvable FQDN name.
- When an IP address is used, it should be explicitely specified as
  such within the `SAN` chain.

That said, this should work :

```
openssl req \
-newkey rsa:2048 \
-x509 \
-nodes \
-keyout file.key \
-new \
-out file.crt \
-subj /CN=Hostname \
-reqexts SAN \
-extensions SAN \
-config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
    <(printf '[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:hostname,IP:192.168.0.1')) \
-sha256 \
-days 3650
```

Comment: Specifically, this is due to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-5.7.3.1 which states "For TLS authentication with X.509 certificates, an identity from the
   DNS namespace MUST be checked against each subjectAltName extension
   of type dNSName present in the certificate.  If no such extension is
   present, then the identity MUST be compared to the (most specific)
   Common Name in the Subject field of the certificate." So, if any SAN exists then the CN is not checked.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but Chrome no longer accepts certificates that fallback to common name. So even if a SAN does not exist, the CN is not checked. So the SAN seems mandatory.

Comment: @krisFR is right because I already tried with certificates without the SAN extension which failed. Specifying the IP field was the solution.

Comment: Life saver. For anyone trying this out on Windows, Cygwin comes with a copy of openssl.cnf here: .\cygwin\etc\defaults\etc\pki\tls\

Also, I had to change my CN=hostname and DNS:hostname lines to be localhost instead of hostname

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Had to add the certificate with this procedure : https://www.corvil.com/kb/how-do-you-get-chrome-to-accept-a-self-signed-certificate

Comment: I was getting "Not a certification authority" when trying to import certificates generated with this command. I found a solution to create a CA first and it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516812 But I think the proper solution is to include an extension/config that sets `basicConstraints=CA:TRUE` Also note that if you are using just an IP you would skip the `DNS:hostname,` part

Answer (score 0):

In addition to krisFR's answer, newer versions of OpenSSL support injecting the subject alt name directly, compacting the command even further:

```
openssl req \
-newkey rsa:2048 \
-x509 \
-nodes \
-keyout file.key \
-new \
-out file.crt \
-subj /CN=Hostname \
-addtext 'subjectAltName=DNS:hostname,IP:192.168.0.1' \
-sha256 \
-days 3650
```

Comment: Specifically since 1.1.1 (released in 2018 -- and EOL a few weeks ago!); see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-command-line