# How do I sign my own SSL certificates so that they cover www and non-www domain names?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate, certificate-authority

When using a commercial Certificate Authority, generating a csr for the common name `www.mysite.com` and sending it to them will result in a certificate being issued that works for both `www.mysite.com` and `mysite.com`.

The signing request is a single name request- just `www.mysite.com`, so nothing special happens at the csr level:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out mysite.com.key 4096

openssl req -new -key mysite.com.key -out mysite.com.csr
common name, ie your name: www.mysite.com
```

But what comes back from the commercial CA is a certificate that works on both www and non-www.

**Question**: How can I take a csr that is just for `www.mysite.com` and, using openssl with my own certificate authority, issue a certificate that works for both `www.mysite.com` and `mysite.com`, just like the commercial companies do?

I know you can modify the csr to add multiple domains with a config file, but only the www version is needed in the csr when using a commercial company. No multi-domain config files are necessary.

Are the commercial CAs modifying the submitted csr to include both versions? Or is there a flag in the signing command that makes the `www` optional?

Can I modify this command to add both www and non-www versions, without changing the csr?

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in mysite.com.csr -CA Authority.crt -CAkey Authority.key -set_serial 12345 -out mysite.com.crt
```

Or is there a simple way to add a second domain to a csr *without* a config file?

```
openssl req -new -key mysite.com.key -out mysite.com.csr
common name, ie your name: mysite.com, www.mysite.com
```

Answer (score 2):

**The CSR doesn't need to be modified.** The certificate is not the CSR, is not a copy of the CSR, and is not created by signing the CSR. The cert is a new object that contains *some* data *copied from* the CSR, and some new data.

In particular, 'commercial' CAs (LetsEncrypt and CACert among others don't charge money, so aren't really commercial) **set the [SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name)** (in the cert) to support multiple 'DNS' names (it can support other types of names also, but you don't want that here). The CommonName attribute in the Subject name *must not* contain multiple domain names, because that can't be matched.

While OpenSSL can do SAN several ways, using `openssl x509 -req -CA/CAkey` makes it simpler: the only option there is to specify an `-extfile` that contains the desired settings. This may need to be an actual file you explicitly create, or on Unix in some shells you can use the `<(command)` syntax to create a hidden temporary file. See:
[Chrome not trusting self-signed cert](https://serverfault.com/questions/1080084/chrome-not-trusting-self-signed-cert)
[Chrome desktop and android refuses to accept trusted self-signed cert](https://serverfault.com/questions/986586/chrome-desktop-and-android-refuses-to-accept-trusted-self-signed-cert)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125319/node-js-self-signed-certificate-is-still-showing-as-not-trusted-in-my-browser
and many more linked at each. (Many involve Chrome because Chrome was a major *reason* to use SAN, but the methods to implement SAN don't depend on the reason.)