# Chrome not trusting self-signed cert

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I have mutual TLS enabled on my nginx reverse proxy. I can view the site only when I have the client cert and custom CA installed in my keychain. This works in Safari and Chrome. However, in Chrome it always says "This cert cannot be trusted" despite having trusted always options selected on both the CA and the client cert. How can I get chrome to trust the cert?

Comment: Dupe https://serverfault.com/questions/845766/generating-a-self-signed-cert-with-openssl-that-works-in-chrome-58 https://serverfault.com/questions/880804/can-not-get-rid-of-neterr-cert-common-name-invalid-error-in-chrome-with-self and others e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172440/generate-x509-ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125319/node-js-self-signed-certificate-is-still-showing-as-not-trusted-in-my-browser . Yes, Chrome since 2017 requires SAN.

Answer (score 0):

The subject alt name wasn't defined. When generating the cert, I ran the following:

```sh
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -sha256 -in mydomain.com.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 1 -out mydomain.com.crt -extfile mydomain.com.ext
```

where I had:

#### mydomain.com.ext

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = mydomain.com
```