# Chrome shows ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when firefox is happy

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

Learning how to work with certificates, maybe will have local CA server. I have server with BMC, so I used it for practicing. Generated CA pair then host pair and then signed host CSR with CA pair to get host crt. I uploaded CA crt to chrome trusted keys repository and host pair to BMC.
Now when I go to the server, I can see that BMC returns correct crt, but chrome shows that connection is not secure. Reason is ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.
However when I click to "Certificate is not valid" I can see both keys and signed certificate is shown as "This certificate is OK.". DNS name used in url = COMMON name. At the same time, for Firefox no problem, it is good with my certs. What may be wrong?

Used this sequence:
#CA PRIVATE

```
openssl genrsa -out CAKEY.pem 2048
```

#CA CERTIFICATE (used in browser). Common name: ca.mydomain.com

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -new -nodes -key CAKEY.pem -days 3650 -out CACERT.pem -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:ca.mydomain.com"
```

#HOST KEY (uploaded to BMC), I need to turn off here password protection, BMC doesn't like password

```
openssl genrsa -out HOSTKEY.pem 2048
```

#HOST CSR. Common name: host1.mydomain.com

```
openssl req -new -key HOSTKEY.pem -out HOSTCSR.pem -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:host1.mydomain.com"
```

#SIGN (uploaded to BMC)

```
openssl x509 -req -CA CACERT.pem -CAkey CAKEY.pem -in  HOSTCSR.pem -out HOSTCRT.PEM -days 3650 -CAcreateserial
```

Comment: Dupe https://serverfault.com/questions/1080084/chrome-not-trusting-self-signed-cert and more linked there

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL's `x509` command doesn't copy the extension from the CSR file to the signed certificate in version 1.1.1 and earlier.

On the [latest version](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html) there's the `-copy_extensions <arg>` option, where ` can be **none**, **copy** or **copyall**.

You're getting the message in Chrome, because your certificate hasn't got the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) extension copied, so it complains. I believe Firefox retains the use of the Subject's CommonName if no Subject Alternative Name extension exists, which is why it doesn't complain.

You can work around this by pointing the `x509` command to another config file with the `-extfile <file>` and the `-extensions <section>` options.  The file `<file>` just needs to have a named section with the extensions you want to add to the certificate:

```
[ my_ext ]
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = host1.mydomain.com
```

Comment: `-extfile` (no `_`). In contrast, `req -new -x509 -addext` does put SAN in the CA cert, but nothing ever looks at SAN in a CA cert and it is completely useless and wasted.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - thanks & fixed :-)

Comment: Thank you, your solution works for me. I don't see here any button to make your answer the solution. Should I press "Answer Your question" ?
`bash#openssl x509 -req -CA CACERT.crt -CAkey CAKEY.pem -in  HOSTCSR.pem -out HOSTCRT.crt -days 3650 -CAcreateserial -extfile ext.txt -extensions my_ext`
`bash#`
`bash#cat ext.txt`
`[ my_ext ]`
`subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash`
`authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always`
`keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment`
`extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth`
`subjectAltName = @alt_names`
`[alt_names]`
`DNS.1 = host1.mydomain.com`

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.