# create a self-signed certificate for a subdomain, the main domain does not belong to me

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority, self-signed-certificate

I have my internet box provider who offers me a free subdomain to connect to my network, ex: xxxxx.provider.com

I have generated a self-signed certificate for the subdomain foo.provider.com
I tried to install it in windows but it does not validate my certificate NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Is it possible to generate a self-signed certificate on a subdomain and the main domain name does not belong to us?

Comment: Are you using Chrome or MSEdge, and did you create the cert to contain SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) _in addition to_ Subject.CommonName? Chrome and new-MSEdge require that, and otherwise give the somewhat misleading error you show. If so dupe https://serverfault.com/questions/1100986/chrome-shows-err-cert-common-name-invalid-when-firefox-is-happy and cross https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172440/generate-x509-err-cert-common-name-invalid .

Comment: Thanks it's exactly that I added -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:xxxx.provider.com" and it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment to my post by dave_thompson_085 helped me solve this,

I added -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:xxxx.provider.com" and reimported the certificate into windows and it works fine now

Here is the command I used to generate my self-signed certificate

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:xxxx.provider.com" -keyout /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt
```

I then answered Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []: xxxx.provider.com

I then imported the certificate into my certificate manager in windows and it worked

Answer (score 2):

A self signed certificate won't be trusted by any browser. What is the purpose of the certificate? If need a certificate that will work in browsers, you can use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't give me a solution for a self signed certificate

Comment: Why do you need self-signed certificates? And why a public authority signed certificate is not a solution for you?

Comment: It's a small server hosted at home which is only used for the family :) that's why I use the host provided by my provider's box

Comment: I understand. I recommend certificates signed by a public CA. Self signed certificates are bad for security.